# Show all terms of a custom taxonomy?

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, terms

I made a few custom taxonomies and I need to show ALL the terms from it, what I achieved so far is showing the taxonomies that are selected/chosen in a custom post type but I need all of them to show, wether it's selected or not.
So that later I can make a filter that filters according to which terms a custom post type value contains.

```
<?php 
$args=array(
  'public'   => true,
  '_builtin' => false
);
$output = 'names'; // or objects
$operator = 'and';
$taxonomies=get_taxonomies($args,$output,$operator); 
if  ($taxonomies) {
  foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
        foreach ( $terms as $term) {
?>
        <li><br><a href="#"><input type="checkbox" name="profile[]" value=""><?php echo $term->name; ?> <br/></a></li>
       <?php 
                }
              }
            }  
            ?>
```

What I have so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At what point does this fail? How much of it works the way you'd like?

Comment: It works the issue is that I can only show the SELECTED terms in a custom post type. I want all of them to show wether selected or not, I don't want to have a dummy post type that has everything selected just to show them.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You need to pass an additional argument to [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms). The default is to hide "empty" terms-- terms which are assigned to no posts.

```
$terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'hide_empty' => false,
]);
```

**EDIT**:

Incase you want to display the name or the slug of the enlisted custom taxonomies being held by the $terms variable you can use this piece of code bellow:

```
foreach ($terms as $term){
  echo $term->slug." : ";
  echo $term->name;
  echo "<br><br>";
}
```

Where `$term->slug` outputs the slug of the taxonomy item that's enlisted and `$term->name` outputs the name of the according taxonomy item.

Comment: Thank you so much! But I want to ask something, why would you create an array inside a variable instead of declaring it above where the first array is shown?

Comment: Simplicity. If the argument array were more complex I would have declared it first (most likely), but for a single argument that is just the most straightforward way to do it. It should work equally well either way.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) that thought me a lot. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Works!! Now I can see what's going on with all the taxonomy options! Some plugins create complex structure in there.

Answer (score 9):

Since 4.5.0, taxonomies should be passed via the ‘taxonomy’ argument in the $args array so:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```

where terms that have no posts are hidden by default.

Answer (score 7):

This code is fetches all category and subcategory custom taxonomies using `get_terms()`:

```
<?php $wcatTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' =>0)); 
   foreach($wcatTerms as $wcatTerm) : 
   ?>
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $wcatTerm->slug, $wcatTerm->taxonomy ); ?>"><?php echo $wcatTerm->name; ?></a>
      <ul class="megaSubCat">
         <?php
            $wsubargs = array(
               'hierarchical' => 1,
               'show_option_none' => '',
               'hide_empty' => 0,
               'parent' => $wcatTerm->term_id,
               'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
            );
            $wsubcats = get_categories($wsubargs);
            foreach ($wsubcats as $wsc):
            ?>
         <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $wsc->slug, $wsc->taxonomy );?>"><?php echo $wsc->name;?></a></li>
         <?php
            endforeach;
            ?>  
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
<?php 
   endforeach; 
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-sm-4">  
                <?php 
                $categories = get_terms( array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'freelancer_type',
                        'hide_empty' => false,
                        'parent' => 0,
                    ) );
                ?>
                <select class="form-control" name="parent_category" id="parent_category">
                    <option value="">Select Category</option>
                    <?php  
                        foreach($categories as $category) {
                            ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></option>
                            <?php 
                        }   
                            
                    ?>      
                </select>
                <select class="form-control" name="child_category" id="child_category">
                    <option value="">Select Sub Category</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).